# Mock s3 bucket as an IAM user using Moto

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, moto

Mock scenario:

I am trying to hit a s3 bucket as a iam user who has s3 deny policy attached. So accessing the s3 bucket will through the Access Denied error. But i can able to see the contents of the bucket..

Below is my code:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def s3():
    with moto.mock_s3():
        yield boto3.client(
            "s3",
            region_name="us-east-1",
            aws_access_key_id="testing",
            aws_secret_access_key="testing",
            aws_session_token="testing",
        )
@pytest.fixture
def bucket_name(s3):
    bucket_name = "test_bucket"
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key="a/b/c/abc.txt")

    return bucket_name

@pytest.fixture()
def iam():
    with moto.mock_iam():
        yield boto3.client(
            "iam",
            region_name="us-east-1",
            aws_access_key_id="testing",
            aws_secret_access_key="testing",
            aws_session_token="testing",
        )
#
#
@pytest.fixture()
def iam_user(iam, s3, bucket_name):
    user_name = "test-user"
    policy_name = "policy1"
    iam.create_user(UserName=user_name)
    policy_document = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": {"Effect": "Deny", "Action": "s3:ListBucket", "Resource": "*"}
    policy_arn = iam.create_policy(PolicyName=policy_name, PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policy_document))["Policy"][
        "Arn"
    ]
    iam.attach_user_policy(UserName=user_name, PolicyArn=policy_arn)
    access_key = iam.create_access_key(UserName=user_name)

    client = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        region_name="us-east-1",
        aws_access_key_id=access_key["AccessKey"]["AccessKeyId"],
        aws_secret_access_key=access_key["AccessKey"]["SecretAccessKey"],
    )

    print(client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name))
def test_check(iam, iam_user):
        print("DOne")
```

**Response**

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'IsTruncated': False, 'Contents': [{'Key': 'a/b/c/abc.txt', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 25, 20, 31, 15, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ETag': '"abcdefghikkd"', 'Size': 0, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD', 'Owner': {'DisplayName': 'webfile', 'ID': 'abcdefgh'}}], 'Name': 'test_bucket', 'MaxKeys': 1000}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, moto will allow any action. It is possible to turn basic policy validation on though - see [this section on the README](https://github.com/spulec/moto#iam-like-access-control).

Turning on validation is done using the `set_initial_no_auth_action_count`-decorator, which essentially means: Don't validate the initial x actions (to allow the user to setup all IAM actions/policies), but validate everything afterwards.

Rewriting the example like so gives me a successful failure:

```
import boto3
import json
import moto
import pytest

from moto.core import set_initial_no_auth_action_count

bucket_name = "test_bucket"


@pytest.fixture()
def s3():
    with moto.mock_s3():
        yield boto3.client(
            "s3",
            region_name="us-east-1",
            aws_access_key_id="testing",
            aws_secret_access_key="testing",
            aws_session_token="testing",
        )


@pytest.fixture
def bucket(s3):
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key="a/b/c/abc.txt")


@pytest.fixture()
def iam():
    with moto.mock_iam():
        yield boto3.client(
            "iam",
            region_name="us-east-1",
            aws_access_key_id="testing",
            aws_secret_access_key="testing",
            aws_session_token="testing",
        )
#
#
@pytest.fixture()
def iam_user(iam, s3):
    user_name = "test-user"
    policy_name = "policy1"
    iam.create_user(UserName=user_name)
    policy_document = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": {"Effect": "Deny", "Action": "s3:ListBucket", "Resource": "*"}
    }
    policy_arn = iam.create_policy(PolicyName=policy_name, PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policy_document))["Policy"][
        "Arn"
    ]
    iam.attach_user_policy(UserName=user_name, PolicyArn=policy_arn)
    access_key = iam.create_access_key(UserName=user_name)

    yield access_key


@set_initial_no_auth_action_count(0)
def test_check(iam, iam_user, bucket):
        access_key = iam_user
        print(access_key)
        client = boto3.client(
            "s3",
            region_name="us-east-1",
            aws_access_key_id=access_key["AccessKey"]["AccessKeyId"],
            aws_secret_access_key=access_key["AccessKey"]["SecretAccessKey"],
        )

        print(client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name))
```

Note that the 'no_auth_action_count' is set to 0. The fixtures are executed first, without any IAM validation. After that, the decorator is applied against the test-method only. As we want to validate every statement inside the function, the count is set to 0.