# Unit Testing by mocking S3 bucket

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mocking, bucket

I am new to unit testing and I require to perform some simple unit tests for an object storage class.

I have a class named OSBucket as follows:

```
def __initBucket(self):        
        
        ecs_session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id="OSKEY",
        aws_secret_access_key="SECRETKEY"
        ) 

        OS_resource = ecs_session.resource('s3', verify=cert, endpoint_url=endpoint)
        self.mybucket = OS_resource.Bucket(OS_BUCKET)
                
        
def get_mybucket(self): 
        
   return self.mybucket


def download_file(self, fileName,filepath):
        
   self.mybucket.download_file(fileName, filepath)

def upload_file(self, filepath,dest_file_name):   
   self.mybucket.upload_file(filepath, '%s%s' % ("/",dest_file_name))
```

The method __initBucket is called in the constructor of the class.

How could I start creating a unit test class to test, for example, the download_file method?

**UPDATE 1**

```
        moto_fake.start()
        conn = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id="fake_id",
        aws_secret_access_key="fake_secret")
        conn.create_bucket(Bucket="OS_BUCKET")    

        os_bucket = OSBucket.OSBucket(thisRun)

        sourcefile = "testingMoto.txt"   
        filePath = os.path.join("/", sourcefile)   
        os_bucket.upload_file(filePath, sourcefile)
```

which executes the `moto_fake.start()` before creating the `os_bucket` object does not work for me.

**UPDATE 2**

Using patch.object to change the endpoint variable to None, makes the test pass

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**First Approach: using python mocks**

You can mock the s3 bucket using standard python mocks and then check that you are calling the methods with the arguments you expect.

However, this approach won't actually guarantee that your implementation is correct since you won't be connecting to s3. For example, you can call non-existing boto functions if you misspelled their names - the mock won't throw any exception.

**Second Approach: using moto**

[Moto](https://pypi.org/project/moto/) is the best practice for testing boto. It simulates boto in your local machine, creating buckets locally so you can have complete end-to-end tests.

I used moto to write a couple of tests for your class (and I might have found a bug in your implementation - check the last test line - those are the arguments needed to make it find the file and not throw an exception)

```
import pathlib
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

import boto3
import moto
import pytest
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from os_bucket import OSBucket


@pytest.fixture
def empty_bucket():
    moto_fake = moto.mock_s3()
    try:
        moto_fake.start()
        conn = boto3.resource('s3')
        conn.create_bucket(Bucket="OS_BUCKET")  # or the name of the bucket you use
        yield conn
    finally:
        moto_fake.stop()


def test_download_non_existing_path(empty_bucket):
    os_bucket = OSBucket()
    os_bucket.initBucket()
    with pytest.raises(ClientError) as e:
        os_bucket.download_file("bad_path", "bad_file")
    assert "Not Found" in str(e)


def test_upload_and_download(empty_bucket):
    os_bucket = OSBucket()
    os_bucket.initBucket()
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
        tmp.write(b'Hi')
        file_name = pathlib.Path(tmp.name).name

        os_bucket.upload_file(tmp.name, file_name)
        os_bucket.download_file("/" + file_name, file_name)  # this might indicate a bug in the implementation
```

Final notes:

- I actually gave a pycon lecture about this exact topic, [watch it here](https://youtu.be/N_9qu5U88Qg?t=754)
- The source code for the lecture can be found [here](https://github.com/pksol/pycon-go-beyond-mocks)

Comment: How is it actually mocking the S3 implementation if we are using the OSBucket class, and moto is used only in empty_bucket() which is not called?

Comment: empty_bucket is called, since it's specified as a dependency in the test functions: `def test_upload_and_download(empty_bucket):`.

As to how it works: basically, boto is making HTTP requests behind the scenes. Moto is targeting those requests and replaceses them with its stub implementation.

So when `moto_fake = moto.mock_s3()` and `moto_fake.start()` are called, then boto is cut from the AWS servers and is interacting with moto instead.

`moto_fake.stop()` is called at the end of every test method, reverting to the normal boto behavior.

Comment: I have implemented this, and the file is actually uploaded to the S3 bucket. For some reason the fake bucket is not being used.

Comment: Did you ensure that the `moto_fake = moto.mock_s3()` and `moto_fake.start()` were executed before you started your connection (`ecs_session = boto3.Session(...`)?

Comment: Please see the new update on the post.

Comment: I believe the reason for failing is the custom URL endpoint that I am using. It is mentioned here [link](https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_s3/test_s3_custom_endpoint.py). But I still do not know how to address this

Comment: is there any issue I am not aware of by using patch to change the endpoint url of the "real" implementation, so that the rest of the mocking works out? @Peter K

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: How would you go about simulating a 403 error via mock_s3?

Comment: @Khorkrak, this stack overflow might be relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66829959/3800552. If it isn't - maybe it's worth opening a new question regarding access control in moto.