# Mock loading a dataframe during testing the function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am fairy new to unit testing in Python and have been using pytest. I have been using fixtures for some unit tests but there is a simple function (see below) that I want to test which has me baffled.

It simply reads parquet file from s3 and as there are duplicate rows in the source data it dedupes on a given list of columns.

So in the unit test I just want to mock loading the data from s3 as I dont want to perform this read. Any pointers on how to approach this?

```
def load_parquet(bucket_name: str,
           bucket_prefix: str,
           folder: str,
           columns_required: list,
           log_date_start: date,
           log_date_end=date):
'''Function to load event data for given date

Args:
    bucket_name: S3 bucket
    bucket_prefix: S3 bucket input path to load parquet
    folder: S3 folder
    log_date_start: Start of logdate
    log_date_end: End of logdate

Returns:
    Dataframe with required columns and deduped
'''


s3_path = f's3://{bucket_name}/{bucket_prefix}/{folder}/'
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=s3_path,
                            columns=columns_required,
                            partition_filter=lambda x: log_date_start <= x["date"] <= log_date_end,
                            dataset=True,
                            use_threads=True)

# Partition filter creates unnecessary columns and drop any duplicates
df_deduped = df[columns_required].drop_duplicates()

return df_deduped
```

Comment: I have only used unittest, for which you would mock `wr.s3.read_parquet`

Comment: `read_parquet` is just a function (?) and can be mocked. Looks like pytest supports this - [Monkeypatching returned objects: building mock classes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-returned-objects-building-mock-classes)

Comment: [Unit Testing by mocking S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71765091/unit-testing-by-mocking-s3-bucket), The moto package seems to be mentioned often.